# Is there a solution of a first order nonlinear PDE?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $a^{ij}, b_{i}, c$ and $f>0$ are smooth function. Suppose $\Lambda I\geq (a^{ij})\geq \lambda I$, where $I$ is identity matrix, $\lambda, \Lambda$ is positive constant. Is there solution of the following equation
$$ \sum_{i,j}^{n}a^{ij}u_{i}u_{j}+\sum_{i}b_{i}u_{i}+cu=f$$

on a domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ or a closed $n-$dimension manifold, where $u_{i}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}$? If not, are there known condidtions ensuring that this equation admits a soulution or locally solution?

Comment: Is $u_i$ the partial derivative with respect to $x_i$, or something else?

Comment: Yes ,it is the partial derivative with respet to $x_{i}$. Thank you  and D. Tampieri for pointing out it.

Comment: There's not always a solution.  Just look at $(u')^2 = -1$ when $n=1$.  Are you asking for sufficient conditions that a solution exist?  Would existence of local solutions suffice for what you want?  Perhaps you can make your question more precise.

Comment: I have a PDE similar with this problem on closed manifold. I just want to find a solution. Both the sufficient conditions and the local solution will help me.

Comment: Could you give me some references

Comment: @liding The eikonal equation $|\nabla u|=f$ is a special case. Lot is known about it.

Comment: This isn't a *general* first order scalar PDE, but of a particular sort:  If $M$ is a Riemannian manifold with metric $a$, $b$ is a vector field on $M$, and $c$ and $f$ are functions on $M$, the equation becomes $$|\nabla u|_a^2 + 2b\,\cdot\nabla u+c\,u - f =0.$$ (In the flat case, the inequalities on $a$ ensure that the metric is complete.)  Writing it as $$|\nabla u+b|_a^2  + c\,u - (f+|b|^2_a) = 0,$$ makes it clearer when solutions exist in a neighborhood of a point.  For example $c(x)\not=0$ or $f(x)+ |b(x)|^2_a>0$ would guarantee local solutions near $x$, by the method of characteristics.

Comment: Thank you very much!